# I'm having problems deserializing enumerations

Tags: c#, json.net, nlog

I am using NLog, and am sending a `LogEventInfo` object across the wire, I do not own this object and therefore I can't decorate it with     `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]`, or maybe I can and I just don't know how

I've tried the following code and it doesn't help

```cs
var strategy = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCaseNamingStrategy();
var sec = new StringEnumConverter(strategy, false);

//TEMP Hard code serialization and message routing for just logs
LogEventInfo info = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LogEventInfo>(msg.Body, sec);
```

Does anyone have any luck getting enums to deserialize and the enum is in a class you don't own?

Here is the message:

```json
{
   "date":"2019-06-04 21:48:24.0753",
   "level":"Error",
   "message":"{\"ApplicationId\":1390760,\"AppStatus\":\"#PG2\",\"Status\":400,\"ErrorCode\": 1053 }",
   "properties":"ResponseBody={\"ApplicationId\":1390760,\"AppStatus\":\"#PG2\",\"Status\":400,\"ErrorCode\": 1053 }|GroupId=392934|ApplicationId=1390760|Status=400",
   "callsite":"HFD.Enterprise.Logging.Tests.LogTest.LoadTest",
   "logger":"WebApiLog",
   "machinename":"BRANDONHOSTVS"
}
```

And here is the exception:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "Error" to type 'NLog.LogLevel'. Path 'level', line 1, position 72. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'NLog.LogLevel'.
   at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.EnsureType(JsonReader reader, Object value, CultureInfo culture, JsonContract contract, Type targetType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: It looks as though `"message"` is an embedded double-serialized JSON string, and `"properties"` contains embedded JSON surrounded by some additional text.  Could this be the problem?  Even if you don't cannot modify the class can you share its reference source, i.e. a [mcve]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your basic problem is that [`LogEventInfo.Level`](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/dev/src/NLog/LogEventInfo.cs#L171) is *not an enum*, it is a class [`LogLevel`](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/blob/dev/src/NLog/LogLevel.cs) that happens to implement `IConvertible` and have a set of global static standard values:

```
public sealed class LogLevel : IComparable, IEquatable<LogLevel>, IConvertible
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets all the available log levels (Trace, Debug, Info, Warn, Error, Fatal, Off).
    /// </summary>
    public static IEnumerable<LogLevel> AllLevels => allLevels;
```

Adding `StringEnumConverter` won't help you (de)serialize such a property.

What's more, it seems that NLog doesn't provide a custom `TypeConverter` for `LogLevel`.  If I call `TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(LogLevel))` the returned value is an instance of the default converter `System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter`, which means Json.NET has no way to convert a serialized `LogLevel` string value back into a `LogLevel` instance.

Nevertheless your JSON sample does represent `Level` as `"level": "Error"`, and so the sending system must have been using some sort of [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) for `LogLevel` that serializes just the `LogLevel.Name`.  We can recreate such a `JsonConverter` quite easily as follows:

```
public class LogLevelConverter : JsonConverter<LogLevel>
{
    public override LogLevel ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, LogLevel existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        switch (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.Null:
                return null;
            case JsonToken.String:
                return LogLevel.FromString((string)reader.Value);
            default:
                throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Unknown token {0}", reader.TokenType));
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, LogLevel value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var logLevel = (LogLevel)value;
        writer.WriteValue(logLevel.Name);
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        if (reader == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}
```

And then use it as follows:

```
var seq = new LogLevelConverter();
var info = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LogEventInfo>(msg.Body, seq);
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3nzhLr).

Comment: "it seems that NLog doesn't provide a custom TypeConverter for LogLevel". How could NLog provide that? (PR likely accepted ;)

Comment: @Julian - just by adding some appropriate [`TypeConverterAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute) to `LogLevel`, e.g. `[TypeConverter(typeof(LogLevelTypeConverter))]`.  See [c# how to implement type converter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43649402).  Having done that, Json.NET will pick it up, see [Json.Net: Serialize/Deserialize property as a value, not as an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40480489).

Comment: @Julian - however, the current implementation is a little odd.  If I do `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LogLevel.Info)` the result is `"2"`, apparently because `((IConvertible)LogLevel.Info).ToType(typeof(string), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))` returns `2`.  Adding in a `TypeConverter` would change this pre-existing (but possibly undesirable) behavior.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/3nzhLr

Comment: FYI a TypeConverter for this  has been added to NLog 4.6.5 (released today)